# How to create and manage two separate session factory with Spring.net and NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4, spring.net

My application is interacting with two separate database. I want to inject session factory with spring.net as usually. when I am creating 2 session factory with two separate dbProviders   , it is showing error. Is there any way to accomplish this task ?

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit. For instance add the error message and tell us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating my own transaction API with Spring AOP.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a [`DelegatingLocalSessionFactory`](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/orm.html#d4e6786) object, available for Spring.NET 1.3.1 and up. According to the docs:

> due to variations in the NHibernate project's ISessionFactory API, this approach is only supported under NHibernate 2.1.2 and NHibernate 3.0

I'm not sure about NHibernate > 3.0.

Comment: I think this is for if we have same database schema and changing the connection on some parameter. But in my case the database are completely separate. I have 2 separate DAL and service layer for both the databases. thoughts ?

Comment: Ah, I missed that from your question. You are absolutely right, a `DelegatingLocalSessionFactory` assumes both database use the same mappings.